# Change underline color for programmatically generated TextInputLayout

Tags: java, android

I try changing the underline color for a programmatically generated TextInputLayout (not a xml generated one):

```
LinearLayout layout=findViewById(R.id.layout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_mw=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(context);
textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(lp_mw);
TextInputEditText field = new TextInputEditText(context);
field.setLayoutParams(lp_mw);
textInputLayout.addView(field);

// change color
int[][] states = new int[][]{
    new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_focused},
    new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_focused},
    new int[]{}
};
int[] hintColors = new int[]{
    R.color.colorPrimary, // unfocused
    R.color.colorAccent, // focused
    R.color.colorPrimary, // default
};
// attempt 1
textInputLayout.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(states, hintColors));
// attempt 2
field.getBackground().setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

layout.addView(textInputLayout);
```

The result:

[image]

The underline color doesn't change at all, What am I doing wrong?.

Answer (score 1):

**Happy New Year 2020.**

---

Actually you are not using color value, instead using resource value

Use `getResources().getColor` like below to get color value.

```
int[] hintColors = new int[] {
    getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary), // unfocused
    getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), // focused
    getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary) // default
};
```

And set the underline color to `TextInputEditText` like below:

```
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(field, new ColorStateList(states, hintColors));
```

Comment: @stramin, Have to checked that?

Answer (score 0):

you have to change color-control-activated and color-control-highlight in your app theme.this is the best way of the change color of text input layout.

```
<style name="YourAppTheme" >
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/Color Name</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/Color Name</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/Color Name</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: sure. I added to the answer